# Why I get different MD5 hash from c# to js?

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, md5

I have a c# function that I use to encrypt password:

```html
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider _md5Provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_password);
            bs = _md5Provider.ComputeHash(bs);
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bs)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
            }

            string _md5password = s.ToString();
```

I try to encrypt the same password in js with crypto-js/md5:

```html
loginUser() {
                console.log(md5(this.password).toString());
            }
```

I get different hash.

Comment: By the way MD5 is a hash, not encryption. You cannot decrypt the original password from the hash value, instead, you compute the hash of the password input by the user, and compare it with another hash value you stored in the db, if they match, then you know the user is inputting correct password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the JavaScript file is saved in an encoding other than UTF-8.

Hash functions like `MD5` computes hash from an array of bytes, not from a string. So you first compute a byte array from the password, using a certain encoding like Unicode, UTF-8 or ANSI; using different encoding you get different values.

To produce the same MD5 hash, save the JavaScript file using UTF-8 (because the C# code is using UTF-8). In this way, in both C# and JavaScript programs the MD5 function computes on byte arrays with identical values, thus the hash will be the same.